# On 15th March, could I have crossed the border from Germany-France and France-Spain?

Tags: compensation, covid-19, flixbus

on 14th March I had a ticket for Frankfurt-Barcelona with FLiXBUS, where the departure time would have been around 3pm and I would have arrived in Barcelona on the 15th March around 9pm. Now, I got a voucher from FLiXBUS because I cancelled the trip myself, but I am now reaching out to the Customer Service Team because I would like to get my money back instead of a voucher.

However, I just searched on Wikipedia and on the FAQ of this site about travel restrictions, but as far as I get it, I **would** have been able to cross the two relevant borders (Germany-France, France-Spain), right?

What I found is that Spain closed its borders on the 16th/17th March, Germany closed its borders later, as far I know, but I didn't find any information on France so far. Because if France hasn't closed its border yet, then of course I cannot get my money back, then FLiXBUS could have offered its service and so I don't think I have a right to get my money back instead of a voucher.

Comment: Without knowing your citizenship or residence status in Spain, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: France has not closed its borders. It has very restricted the freedom of travel but not totally closed down internal nor international travel.

Answer (score 1):

France hadn't “closed” its border on the 16th of March. France always insisted that borders needed to be kept open and lamented unilateral action by other European countries.

On the evening of March 16, France announced a new lock-down order, effective on March 17 at noon that formally made it illegal to travel outside of a limited number of purposes (unavoidable professional travel, etc.) Since then, France tightened the rules but still hasn't taken any specific measures regarding Schengen borders. It's largely moot as travel inside the country is now severely limited.

Flixbus announced a total suspension of their operations in Germany from March 18th.

Answer (score -2):

Since relevant information is missing:

- Citizenship (Spanish: yes or no)
- place of residence (Spain: yes or no)
- date you cancelled the trip (before the 14th of March: yes or no)

no precise answer can be given.

---

Since the State of Emergency in Spain was announced on the 14th of March, it is likely that any non-Spanish citizen or resident would have been refused entry at the Spanish border if checked.

Since you have allready accepted the voucher, your chances of getting a refund is less likely.

Had you cancelled **after** the State of Emergency was known, then a refund would have been probably possible due to *Force Majeure*.

Comment: The question is about France, not Spain and is fully answerable. Also, answers are not the right way to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Relaxed **and France-Spain?** The destination is obviously Spain, thus clarification about fulling the conditions to enter Spain is justified. Also due the French the restrictions a justification for travel is needed. Returning to place of residence is for all 3 countries is a justified reason. Your downvote is unjustified.

Comment: The question is still solely about France. It's what's being asked, re-read the question if you need to. And if you thought it was about Spain but couldn't be answered without additional info then you shouldn't post an answer.

Comment: @Relaxed you are failing to see the whole picture. Justified travel **through** France with a bus to Barcelona (in Spain), based on their new regulations introduced hours before the Spanish State of Emergency was, would be only accepted if the OP is a resident or citizen of Spain. So the information is relevant.

Comment: Yes but it's still not what was asked. Since this is so transparently obvious, it should be easy to understand that I am not failing to see anything but rather making a different point. My issue is that this is not an answer but an extended comment. That's not what answers are for. Instead of making irrelevant comments, I believe there are still many incorrect answers of yours you never bother to edit...